# WIX: InstallValidate adding REMOVE property when installing MSI?

Tags: wix

I'm creating a MSI. When I try to install it through

```
msiexec /lvxe log.txt /i product.msi
```

I see the following in the log file:

```
MSI (s) (2C:BC) [06:22:05:579]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REMOVE property. Its value is 'ALL'.
Action ended 6:22:05: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
```

Which prevents a custom action I have from running because its condition is (Not Installed and Not Remove).

Any idea? I thought REMOVE=ALL is set only for uninstalls. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would need to see more of the logfile.  You can email it to me if you'd like.

Comment: Sure, would you send me your address, or a pointer to a container of it, or tell if there's a specific section you want to look at. Thanks!

Comment: chrpai@deploymentengineering.com.   The whole log ( zipped ) is fine.

Comment: Ok, I was able to find the issue based on your comments: Feature's Level was being set to 30, which seems to cause REMOVE to be set to ALL, as no features to install exist. After setting Level to 1, installation proceeds. Thanks a lot Christopher. Wish I could give you an arrow up and mark your comment as answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is based on a logfile that I was sent:

Per the Windows Installer documentation:

> **Default Value** If no value is specified, the install level defaults
>   to 1.

There was 1 feature with a Level of 30 therefore wasn't being installed.

Since no features were scheduled to install, this was by definition an uninstall and InstallValidate set the REMOVE property to ALL.

[INSTALLLEVEL Property (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369536(VS.85).aspx)